# Getting followers in a chronological order. Google plus API

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I know how to get people from circle. But how could I know which user I circled when or when other users circled me?

I've gone through the Google Plus API again and again but still haven't found a solution.

Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like that information is exposed in the API.  There is nothing there about when you circled someone.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I missed it somewhere but your response reassured me.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like that information is exposed in the API. There is nothing there about when you circled someone.

[People: list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list) when requesting visible pleases to return everyone that is visible to you

> "visible": The list of people who this user has added to one or more
>   circles, limited to the circles visible to the requesting application.

It returns a list of [people.resource](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people#resource) there does not appear to be any information returned about when they where circled.